# How to force UIImagePickerController's editing to square or proportional?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController to allow the user to select a photo of himself to use as a player avatar image.  When I show a UIImagePickerController inside of a UIPopoverController on the iPad, and when I setAllowsEditing:YES, I get a square editing area inside of the picker if the device is held in portrait mode.  But if I rotate the device to landscape, the cropping area becomes rectangular.  Is this the expected behavior of UIImagePickerController?  Or am I doing something wrong?  Is there a way to force the editing behavior to be 1:1 ratio or proportional?  The docs seem to indicate that there is no control and that it should always be square: "When using built-in editing controls, the image picker controller enforces certain options. For still images, the picker enforces a square cropping as well as a maximum pixel dimension."